# Javascript dynamic creation of iframe doesn't load src

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following piece of code that should dynamically load an iframe with the Google homepage as an example. The iframe gets created but the src is not loaded:

```
var theIframe2 = document.createElement("iframe");
theIframe2.setAttribute("id", "main-iframe2");
theIframe2.setAttribute("src", "http://www.google.co.uk");

theIframe2.style.width = "300px";
theIframe2.style.height = "200px"; 
theIframe2.style.position = "absolute";
theIframe2.style.top = "0px";
theIframe2.frameBorder = 1;

var containerDiv2 = document.getElementById('container');
containerDiv2.appendChild(theIframe2);
```

It's also on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JxhFE/1/

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Colin.

Comment: Google prevents you from loading its page in a frame using the X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

Answer (score 3):

You can't show `google.co.uk` in an `IFrame` in your domain. Due to security reasons `Google` only allows it's homepage to be embedded from the same origin. (`X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` header.)

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thank you!